# Access Dynamic IIF reference on form

Tags: ms-access

I cant seem to figure out how to reference a combo box value on a form in another textboxs sum iif function.  The sample of what I am trying to do is below, with the reference to "TestCombo" the value I want to change based on who is selected.  I tried using CHR(34) quotes, and I cant seem to figure it out.

```
SUM(iif([SaleStatus]= 'Pending' And [SalesAdvisor] = [TestCombo],1,0))
```

This same function works if I do the following

```
SUM(iif[SaleStatus]= 'Pending' And [SalesAdvisor] = 'TestAdvisor',1,0))
```

That led me to believe I needed quotes, which I expected, but that doesn't work either, such as the example below.

```
SUM(iif"[SalesStauts]= 'Pending' And [SalesAdvisor] = " & chr(39) & [TestCombo] & chr(39) & "",1,0))
```

Can somebody help me use the combo box as a dynamic reference to the sum iif?

Comment: Verify that the control names are identical to the bound fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your combo is equal to 'TestAdvisor'? It is quite common to have a numeric bound column and a text display. If you have more than one column in the combo, you will need to refer to the column property to get the text column. If you include the RecordSource for the combo in your question, it will be easy to see.